# Let $E$ be a separable Banach space and $A$ an uncountable subset of the unit sphere. Does $A$ have accumulation point?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a separable Banach space and let $S_E=\{x \in E \ | \ |x| = 1\}$. If $A \subset S_E$ is uncountable, must $A$ have a accumulation point?

Obviously if $A$ is countable the answer is no if $E$ is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, if $A \subset X$ is uncountable where $X$ is any separable and complete metric space (or for that matter, any complete second-countable topological space), then $A$ must have an accumulation point.

One proof is as follows: take $\{x_n\}$ to be a sequence which is dense in $X$.  Define
$$
B_{j,k} = \left\{x \in X : |x - x_j| < \frac 1k\right\}
$$
We have $X = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_{j,k}$ for all $k = 1,2, \dots$.

There must exist a $j_1$ such that $A \cap B_{j_1,1}$ is uncountable.  Let $A_1 = A \cap B_{j_1,k}$.  Continue in such a fashion for $k \geq 2$; at each step, there must exist a $j_k$ such that $A_{k-1} \cap B_{j_k,k}$ is uncountable.

Select an arbitrary sequence $\{a_n\} \subset A$ with $a_k \in A_k$.  The sequence $a_n$ is Cauchy and therefore convergent, so $A$ must have an accumulation point.

Comment: Thank you kindly!